# iOS Game Center Alias unique ID

Tags: ios, game-center

Is the alias for iOS Game Center a unique ID (that can be used as a unique user key or identifier in an external database)? Or, is it not unique?

Is the only unique identification ID the G:... code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the alias is not unique. Use the player id instead.